# How to create custom HTML form in Wordpress Admin Panel?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

Is it possible to add custom HTML in Word Press Admin Panel? I am trying to create a table in my Admin Panel. I am unable to understand where to write HTML for this table. Kindly help me.

Comment: Try this link http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/ this will help you. how to design your admin area.

Comment: take help from [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own plugin for wordpress as that would be the easiest way to do it. Otherwise you risk losing what you created during a core or plugin update. You can follow [THIS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Creating_a_Plugin) to get you started

Comment: This is not the thing he is looking for.

Comment: So you down vote me because you know exactly what he is looking for? He wants to "create" a custom table. he didn't say he wanted a new admin theme or create a new theme

Answer (score 1):

try reading [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91693/adding-a-custom-admin-page##answer-91696).

Here's a demo [file](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Admin-Menu-Demo).

Hope it helps.